# How to delete/replace everything in column after certain character fetched with awk?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Example of file.txt:

```
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/4/23/82.png 200
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/2/48/154.png?fefsfes 200
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/3/45/433.png?gtdrdrg 200
```

I need to delete this:

```
.png
.png?fefsfes
.png?gtdrdrg
```

I use this

```
$ cat file.txt | awk '{ print $1","$2}'
```

to get result:

```
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/4/23/82.png,200
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/2/48/154.png?fefsfes,200
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/3/45/433.png?gtdrdrg,200
```

Can I somehow fetch column with `awk '{ print $1}'` and delete everything after last number?

Wanted result:

```
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/4/23/82,200
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/2/48/154,200
/map/1.0.0/cd/base/3/45/433,200
```

Comment: You mean something like this `sed 's/\.png.*\ /,/' file.txt`?

Comment: How can I include that in this: $ cat file.txt | awk '{ print $1","$2}'

Comment: It replaces all of that in one command (in theory).

Comment: But if I put that as: $ cat file.txt | awk '{ print $1","$2}' | sed 's/\.png.*\ /,/' nothing happens

Comment: There is no need for `cat` or `awk`, just the `sed` command will handle everything.  `$ sed 's/\.png.*\ /,/' file.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the essence of your awk command, then you can simply `sub` away the unwanted trailing portion of `$1`

```
awk '{sub(/\.png.*$/,"",$1); print $1","$2}' file
```

or (perhaps more awkishly)

```
awk '{sub(/\.png.*$/,"",$1)}1' OFS=, file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below awk solution -

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=".png| "} {print $1,$NF}' kk.txt |tr ' ' ','
```

using multiple field seperator.

Comment: Outside the awk tr is working fine to remove the space with comma but inside the awk it is throwing below error - 

awk 'BEGIN{FS=".png| "} {print $1,$NF|tr ' ' ','}' kk.txt
awk: line 2: missing } near end of file
awk 'BEGIN{FS=".png| "} {print $1,$NF|"tr ' ' ','"}' kk.txt
awk: line 1: runaway string constant "tr  ...